# Start-AzureSqlDatabaseExport Object Reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: azure, automation, export, backup, workflow

I'm not sure how to debug this, assuming it's not a problem with the cmdlet.  I'm trying to replace the automated SQL export with an automation workflow, but I can't seem to get Start-AzureSqlDatabaseExport to work -- it keeps getting the following warning and error messages.

d4fc0004-0c0b-443e-ad1b-310af7fd4e2a:[localhost]:Client Session Id: 'c12c92eb-acd5-424d-97dc-84c4e9c4f914-2017-01-04 
19:00:23Z'

d4fc0004-0c0b-443e-ad1b-310af7fd4e2a:[localhost]:Client Request Id: 'd534f5fd-0fc0-4d68-8176-7508b35aa9d8-2017-01-04 
19:00:33Z'

**Start-AzureSqlDatabaseExport : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

At DBBackup:11 char:11
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Start-AzureSqlDatabaseExport], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.SqlDatabase.Database.Cmdlet.StartAzureSqlDatabaseExport

This seems similar to some other questions, but they seem to be unanswered or not applicable. I did have a similar procedure working in the Powershell environment. I replaced that procedure with the automated export from Azure, which seems like a poor choice now!  I've tried a number of variations, using sqlcontext and databasename instead of database, for example.

Here's my code with sensitive parts replaced with ****:

```
workflow DBBackup {

param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]  
    [string] $dbcode
    )

$cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "admindbcredentials"
$VerbosePreference = "Continue"

inlineScript {

    $dbcode = $using:dbcode
    $cred = $using:cred

    if ($dbcode -eq $null) 
    {
        Write-Output "Database code must be specified"
    }
    Else
    {
        $dbcode = $dbcode.ToUpper() 

        $dbsize = 1
        $dbrestorewait = 10
        $dbserver = "kl8p7d444a"
        $stacct = $dbcode.ToLower()
        $stkey = "***storagekey***"


        Write-Verbose "DB Server '$dbserver' DB Code '$dbcode'"
        Write-Verbose "Storage Account '$stacct'"
        $url = "https://$dbserver.database.windows.net"             
        $sqlctx = New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerContext -ManageUrl $url -Credential $cred
        # $sqlctx = New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerContext -ManageUrl $url -Credential $cred
        $stctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $stacct -StorageAccountKey $stkey
        $dbname = "FSUMS_" + $dbcode        
        $dt = Get-Date
        $timestamp = $dt.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "_" + $dt.ToString("HHmmss") 
        $bkupname = $dbname + "_" + $timestamp + ".bacpac"

        $stcon = Get-AzureStorageContainer -Context $stctx -Name "backups"
        $db = Get-AzureSqlDatabase -Context $sqlctx -DatabaseName $dbname

        Write-Verbose "Backup $dbname to $bkupname in storage account $stacct"
        Start-AzureSqlDatabaseExport $sqlctx -DatabaseName $dbname -StorageContainer $stcon -BlobName $bkupname        
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport` instead. This command will return export status object. If you want a synchronous export you can check for "export status" in a loop.

Comment: It's telling me that it doesn't recognize that.  I haven't converted to using resource groups -- could that be the problem?  I just used the default resource group.

Error Message:

New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport : The term 'New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the 
path is correct and try again.

Comment: Check whether you have AzureRM module installed.  Get-Module –ListAvailable AzureRM* . If not.  Do Install-Module AzureRM and Install-AzureRM. Try again New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport

Comment: I'm trying to do this from Automation at this point.  I see that the version on my local PowerShell for AzureRM.Sql is 2.4.0 but it's 1.0.3 when I run it from Automation.

Comment: I've actually broken down and started a support ticket with Microsoft -- think there is something funny going on.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following lines corrected the problem:

In the workflow before inlineScript:

```
$cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "admincredentials"

    (where admincredentials was an asset with my admin login credentials)
```

and inside the inlineScript:

```
Add-AzureAccount $cred
Select-AzureSubscription "My subscription"
```

Some runbooks don't seem to need this, but probably best to always include it.

Comment: You always need to be authenticated when you do any manipulations with your Azure resources. Otherwise Azure doesn't know who you are and whether you are permitted to do anything.

Comment: Azure Automation provides default credentials and subscription, but best not to rely on it, I think.  In my case, it picked the wrong subscription sometimes, for no apparent reason (it's not the default).